# Where to read on Lindström's theorem?

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic

What's a good place to read the proof and maybe some other relevant info on Lindstrom's theorem? (I mean the characterization of first order logic.)

My background in logic is an introductory course in Model Theory and a graduate course in set theory (covering up to forcing).

I want to present this result as a class project and the presentation should last about 45 minutes, an hour at most. Is it viable?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/opetus/lt/lindstrom_theorem1.pdf ? I also have some slides by Jouko Väänänen with an exposition of the proof (they were part of a Model theory course I took). I can send them to you if you want. I think a sketch of a proof is viable in 45 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book by Ebbinghaus-Flum-Thomas covers this in the last chapter, and does a pretty good job; you can also look at the gigantic book "Model-theoretic logics," where Lindstrom's theorem is covered in either the first or second chapter.

In terms of a presentation, I think this is just viable *if the class has already seen the characterization of first-order equivalence via back-and-forth systems*. This is after all the crucial ingredient in Lindstrom's argument - the ability to form a structure $\mathcal{E}(A, B)$ representing the elementary equivalence of $A$ and $B$, and a countable nonstandard version of which represents the *isomorphism* between analogous structures $A'$ and $B'$. If the class has not seen this, then I think there's no satisfying way to do Lindstrom's theorem - you'll be forced to blackbox the most interesting piece. Instead, I'd recommend presenting this characterization; it's definitely doable (and fun) in 45 minutes, and you can end by stating Lindstrom's theorem as an application.

---

EDIT: You asked in a comment below about the characterization I mention. So let me give this characterization, together with an outline of the proof of Lindstrom's theorem:

The characterization is essentially via [Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game), appropriately formalized. For a pair of structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ in a relational language *(adding functions is a bit tedious, and there's no reason to do this since we can just replace each function with its graph)*, say that a *partial isomorphism* is a bijection $f: \alpha\rightarrow\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta$ subsets of $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ which preserves and reflects the relations of the structures. Note that the empty map is a partial isomorphism.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, an **$n$ back-and-forth system** between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is a sequence $I_0, I_1, ..., I_n$ of sets such that

- Each $I_i$ is a set of partial isomorphisms from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$.
- **Forth**: for each $i<n$, each $f\in I_{i+1}$ and each $a\in\mathcal{A}$, there is some $g\in I_i$ with $f\subseteq g$ and $a\in dom(g)$.
- **Back**: for each $i<n$, each $f\in I_{i+1}$ and each $b\in\mathcal{B}$, there is some $g\in I_i$ with $f\subseteq g$ and $a\in ran(g)$.

Note the decreasing index: the point is that we can use the back-and-forth properties a few times to expand some $f\in I_j$, but never more than $j$ times.

Then we have:

> $\mathcal{A}\equiv\mathcal{B}$ iff for each $n$ there is an $n$-back-and-forth system between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

Roughly speaking, the existence of an $n$ back-and-forth system means that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ agree on $n$-quantifier sentences.

We could also imagine an "$\infty$-back-and-forth system" where we can just keep going forever. Such a system characterizes *isomorphism* in the case of countable structures (among uncountable structures, it characterizes the weaker relation of *potential isomorphism*, i.e. isomorphism in some forcing extension), and it turns out that this can be viewed as a nonstandard version of the elementary equivalence characterization above. This is the key step of Lindstrom's theorem: to pass from a structure witnessing the elementary equivalence of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, to a structure witnessing the isomorphism (via compactness) of countable (via Lowenheim-Skolem) structures $\mathcal{A}'$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ which are $\mathcal{L}$-equivalent to $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you be more explicit on what you mean by the characterization of first order equivalence? I imagine I'll find it in Ebbinghaus-Flum-Thomas as well, right? Thanks again.

Comment: @Mingus Ask and ye shall receive! I believe it is called "Fraisse's theorem," by the way, although I'm not 100% on that. And yes, it is in EFT.

Comment: Do you know of someplace where I can read more on the concept of potential isomorphisms? Do you know the poset used to introduce the isomorphism in the extension? Thanks again.

Comment: @Mingus The poset used is just any poset making both structures countable. That is, the following are equivalent (and I think this is due to Barwise and Karp but I'm not sure): (i) $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ satisfy the same $\mathcal{L}_{\infty\omega}$-sentences. (ii) Duplicator has a winning strategy in the back-and-forth game. (iii) $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$ in *every* generic extension in which $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are both countable. (iv) $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$ in *every* generic extension in which $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are both countable

Comment: The equivalence between (iii) and (iv) can be viewed as a general instance of [Mostowski absoluteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness), as follows. Suppose we had two forcings $\mathbb{P}_0$ and $\mathbb{P}_1$ each making $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ countable, with the first forcing that they are isomorphic and the second forcing that they aren't. Let $G\times H$ be $\mathbb{P}_0\times\mathbb{P}_1$-generic, and let $a, b$ be reals in $V[H]$ coding copies of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$. (cont'd)

Comment: Now $V[G\times H]$ sees that $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$, since the isomorphism from $V[G]$ lifts up to $V[G\times H]$; but this means that $V[G\times H]$ satisfies the $\Sigma^1_1$ sentence "the structures coded by $a$ and $b$ are isomorphic." By Mostowski absoluteness, that sentence is absolute back to $V[H]$.

Comment: (In my initial response, the "every" in (iii) should be replaced with "some", to make it different from (iv) - too late to edit now.)